# Cant Upload Images to Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am working on e-commerce project and i am stuck at this. Whenever admin adds new product,it should also add image related to the product. So i added the the column with ImageField but i am getting error again and again. Here is my code for models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(db_column='image' , blank=True, null=True)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    
    def image_tag(self):
        if self.image:
            return mark_safe('<img src="%s"/>' % self.image.url)
        else:
            return 'No Image Found'
    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
```

and in admin.py

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('product_id', 'name','image_tag', 'info')
    readonly_fields = ('image',)

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

But every time i get this error

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:'bytes' object has no attribute 'url'
```

I tried using escape but it still not displaying images.I am using MySQL existing database. I could really use the help. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to add `upload_to` argument to ImageField as seen here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

Comment: But i am saving images in MySQL database, what should i put there in ```upload_to```?

Comment: In that case you should consider using a `BinaryField` instead and add a method to generate a url. But it doesn't seem a good idea. Django docs also says so: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield

Comment: Currently your DB stores the image as bytes and so it doesn't have a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are storing image in your database as bytes, which Django does not prefers instead you should first specify `MEDIA_ROOT` this is folder where your image will be saved and only the URL will be saved in the database. Docs [[SOURCE]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage)

I assume you have already setup `MEDIA` settings and have installed `Pillow`.
Your `ImageField` will look like,

```
# No need to specify db_column as Django already stores by default field's name.
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
```

Now in your templates you can get the image by,

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/{{ profile.photo }}" id='profile-photo'>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have changed my mind of saving images in Database and trying your solution. But i could not do it either. I have set the ```uploads_to``` then change image source tag still all it was showing is path of the image instead of image.

Comment: I guessed it worked after trying little more ! Thank very much really appreciate the help.